# Appending text to profile in ubuntu

Tags: linux, shell-script

I want to append following text to my `profile` file from script:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun"
CATALINA_HOME="/usr/share/tomcat6"
CATALINA_BASE="/var/lib/tomcat6"
ANT_HOME="/usr/share/ant"
export JAVA_HOME CATALINA_HOME CATALINA_BASE ANT_HOME
```

Kindly let me know how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [here-document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) and redirection:

```
cat << End >> .profile
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun"
CATALINA_HOME="/usr/share/tomcat6"
CATALINA_BASE="/var/lib/tomcat6"
ANT_HOME="/usr/share/ant"
export JAVA_HOME CATALINA_HOME CATALINA_BASE ANT_HOME
End
```

Comment: will it work if I use `cat << END >> /etc/profile`

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot: Yes, so long as whoever runs the script has write-permissions on /etc/profile. You might want to make your script check that these lines are not already there.

Comment: and how will I make it check if lines are already there?

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot: by learning shell-scripting :-)   See `if` and `grep` in your man-pages.

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't comment on RedGrittyBrick's answer, here is something I want to point out. In situations when these lines have references to variables (e.g., PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin), you should put the word End in quotes (as in "End"). This prevents the shell from doing any parameter expansions (unless that is what you need).